# Typescript initialization error when compiling

Tags: angularjs, json, typescript, intellij-idea, package.json

Getting TypeScript error in IntelliJ-Idea 2017.1.1 IDE

I have tried Enabled JavaScript, NodeJS and TypeScript Compiler.

I have tried everything, but not getting fix, may I missing somewhere.

> Error: Initialisation error (typescript). Cannot read property 'createHash of undefined

Can any one help me to solve?

[image]

[image]

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "TempPractice",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "First Angular App",
  "license": "MIT",
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git@github.com:angularjs-de/angularjs-typescript-seed.git"
  },
  "main": "app/app.ts",
  "scripts": {
    "tsc": "tsc",
    "tsc:w": "tsc -w",
    "lite": "lite-server",
    "typings": "typings",
    "postinstall": "typings install",
    "update-deps": "npm update",
    "postupdate-deps": "bower update",
    "prestart": "npm install",
    "start": "http-server -a localhost -p 8000 -c-1 ./app",
    "pretest": "npm install",
    "test": "karma start karma.conf.js",
    "test-single-run": "karma start karma.conf.js --single-run",
    "preupdate-webdriver": "npm install",
    "update-webdriver": "webdriver-manager update",
    "preprotractor": "npm run update-webdriver",
    "protractor": "protractor e2e-tests/protractor.conf.js",
    "update-index-async": "node -e \"var fs=require('fs'),indexFile='app/index-async.html',loaderFile='app/bower_components/angular-loader/angular-loader.min.js',loaderText=fs.readFileSync(loaderFile,'utf-8').split(/sourceMappingURL=angular-loader.min.js.map/).join('sourceMappingURL=bower_components/angular-loader/angular-loader.min.js.map'),indexText=fs.readFileSync(indexFile,'utf-8').split(/\\/\\/@@NG_LOADER_START@@[\\s\\S]*\\/\\/@@NG_LOADER_END@@/).join('//@@NG_LOADER_START@@\\n'+loaderText+'    //@@NG_LOADER_END@@');fs.writeFileSync(indexFile,indexText);\""
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^4.4.4",
    "@angular/compiler": "^4.4.4",
    "@angular/core": "^4.4.4",
    "@angular/forms": "^4.4.4",
    "@angular/http": "^4.4.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.4.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.4.4",
    "@angular/router": "^4.4.4",
    "angular-in-memory-web-api": "^0.5.0",
    "angular-route": "^1.6.6",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "rxjs": "^5.4.3",
    "ts-node": "^3.3.0",
    "typescript": "^2.5.3",
    "typings": "^2.1.1",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.18"
  }
}
```

**tsconfig.json**

```
  {
     "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "system",
        "removeComments": true,
        "preserveConstEnums": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "sourceMap": true,
        "inlineSources": true,
        "target": "es5"

     },
     "compileOnSave": false,
     // Points folders and file to exclude
     "exclude": [
        "node_modules",
        "typings/main",
        "typings/main.d.ts"
     ]
  }
```

**typings.json**

```
  {  
     "ambientDependencies": {  
        "es6-shim": "github:DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/es6-shim/es6-shim.d.ts#7de6c3dd94feaeb21f20054b9f30d5dabc5efabd",  
        "jasmine": "github:DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/jasmine/jasmine.d.ts#7de6c3dd94feaeb21f20054b9f30d5dabc5efabd"  
     }  
  }
```

Comment: `InitialiSation error` this does not seem to be a real error. Where and when exactly do you observe this error?

Comment: When I have create main.ts file

Comment: or any TypeScript file

Comment: I have added the error screen shot in my question post pls.. look

Comment: Try the following: 1) close the IDE; 2) remove `node_modules` directory entirely; 3) run `npm install`; 4) reopen your IDE; 5) test whether .ts files work now.

Comment: Thanks I'll try and update.

Comment: I have follows the steps, but same error getting.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

TypeScript version you are using (2.5.3) is not compatible with TypeScript service integration available in **2017.1.1**. The issue is caused by breaking changes in service API (https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/15433).

[WEB-26641](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-26641) is fixed in **2017.1.3**, so it's compatible with all TypeScript versions up to 2.4.
But 2.5.x adds more breaking changes. So, if you need using IDEA with TypeScript 2.5.3, please make sure to update to the most recent IDEA version.